# Check digit number : Find the maximum number of distinct ways

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Find the maximum number of elements in a set containing combinations of three digits (from 0 through 9) with the following rules:

1. Each digit can be used more than once.
2. Any two combinations in the set can have at most 1 digit in the same place.

Example:

- 922, 433, and 055 can co-exist in the set.
- 922, 432 and 425 is ok as well, since each pair of combinations only have one number in common in the same place.
- However, 123, 124 cannot both be in the set, because they share two numbers in the same place (1, and 2).

Additionally, list the combinations in your solution.

Comment: Do we need to make a set of 3-digit combinations (and maximise its cardinality) or a single 6-digit combination (and find the number of ways to do so)?

Comment: a set of 3-digit combinations (and maximise its cardinality)

Comment: I think the edit I proposed should clarify the question.

Comment: @gentlePurpleRain. I think this is not math problem, you can not answer the question using math (addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc),  you have to use logic to find the maximum numbers.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya It seems like basic combinatorics to me. If you disagree, you're welcome to bring it up in [meta] and see what others think. If the community disagrees with me, we can certainly give the question another shot.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain As a combinatorics graduate student, this isn't a basic or rote combinatorics problem, there's a bit of cleverness involved. Only 21 people have seen the question so far, why not wait to see what the community thinks before unilaterally closing?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I will defer to the expert in the field. We can give it a shot and allow it to be judged on its own merits.

Comment: Much appreciated, @GentlePurpleRain :^)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I think it's an edit by John Mark Perry that made it look like a boring counting problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> $100$.

### Mathematical construction and proof:

> Take the first two digits arbitrarily, say $a$ and $b$, and make the third digit $a+b \pmod{10}$. Do it for all possible ordered pairs of $a$ and $b$. There are obviously $10^2=100$ such pairs, and hence we get $100$ such combinations. Clearly, if some two combinations match in two places, they must match in the third place as well, which means they are actually the same combination.

### Explicit list:

> [image]
>  (For a text version, please see the revision history.)

### Proof that we can't do better:

> There are only $10^2=100$ possible combinations for the first two digits, so if someone can conjure up a set with more than $100$ elements, some two must have the same pair of first two digits by Pigeonhole Principle. So contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Comment: As the question says, list the numbers !

Comment: @JamalSenjaya OK, did that. If anyone wants to put that in a spoiler-block, feel free to do so.

Comment: Not sure why it's exactly necessary to list all the numbers... O_o

Comment: OK, I have put the list in an image and spoiler-blocked it.